# Disable eslint disable overrides?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint

Is there a way to disable use of eslint disable overrides?
For example, block the use of `/* eslint disable-next-line */`, etc so that a specific rule is enforced always without exception

Answer (score 0):

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-inline-comments

> To disable all inline config comments, use the noInlineConfig setting. For example:

```
{
  "rules": {...},
  "noInlineConfig": true
}
```

Unfortunately it's only global, you can't target a specific rule.